# how to specify categorical units in matploblib

Tags: matplotlib

I've got some code that looks like this:

```
ax.bar(x, y, label=label, alpha=0.5)
```

and the problem is it's emitting this annoying `INFO` to my log and (I think) sometimes changing my labels. It's annoying because it's in an inner loop of a larger program. I'd rather not suppress matploblib messages because I'm a novice at it and don't want to miss anything.

```
Using categorical units to plot a list of strings that are all parsable as floats or dates. If these strings should be plotted as numbers, cast to the appropriate data type before plotting.
```

Is there a way I can tell matplotlib not to change my labels or warn me about them even if they look like numbers (i.e., without changing my labels)?

Comment: I think that the unfortunate short answer is "no". Looking at the [matplotlib source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/main/lib/matplotlib/category.py), there doesn't seem to be a condition to suppress the message.